# Why cannot get the ZeroMQ ROUTER / ROUTER pattern to work?

Tags: c#, zeromq

I am trying to implement a **`ROUTER / ROUTER`** pattern in VS using ZeroMQ and I cannot seem to get the thing working. From what I can tell, I know the server works fine since I tried it with other types of client sockets without any issue. But on making it a `ROUTER`, it does not work.

**Would anyone have an idea as to how to fix the client?**

My code is as follows:

```
static string ip = "127.0.0.1";
static string port = "5555";
static string endpoint = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}", ip, port);

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(StartRouterServer,TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartRouterClient(0), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        Thread.Sleep(10000000);
    }

static void StartRouterClient(int i)
    {
        using (ZContext context = new ZContext())
        using (ZSocket router = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.ROUTER))
        {
            router.IdentityString = "client: " + i;
            router.Connect(endpoint);
            //send message
            router.SendMore(new ZFrame(router.IdentityString));
            router.SendMore(new ZFrame());
            router.Send(new ZFrame("Hi"));

            using (ZMessage received = router.ReceiveMessage())
            {//on receiving a reply from the server, you come here.
                Console.WriteLine("Received a message back from the server!!");
            }
        }
    }

static void StartRouterServer()
    {
        using (ZContext context = new ZContext())
        using (ZSocket router = new ZSocket(context, ZSocketType.ROUTER))
        {
            router.IdentityString = "router";
            router.Bind(endpoint);
            Console.WriteLine("The server is bound to {0}", router.LastEndpoint);

            while (true)
            {
                using (ZMessage received = router.ReceiveMessage())
                {//what you do when you receive the message.
                    Console.WriteLine("received a message!");
                    router.SendMore(received[0]);
                    router.SendMore(new ZFrame());
                    router.Send(new ZFrame("Hi back!!"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, nvm, I messed up the addressing. For this pattern each of the routers needs to know of each other's identity. That is the way this works. 
i.e. in the StartRouterClient() method,
  I had to replace `router.SendMore(new ZFrame(router.IdentityString));`
  with `router.SendMore(server.IdentityString);`

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the client socket is created and attempting to send before the server socket has bound to port 5555.  If that happens the client socket will drop the message.

Try putting a **`Thread.Sleep( 1000 )`** between the calls to `Task.Factory.StartNew()` to allow the server socket time to be created and bind.

<sub>( I wrote a similar code in python and it worked, so long as server socket was sure to be bound before client connected and send. )</sub>

Comment: i tried. did not work. It was the addressing that I had screwed up. But thank you for your help!